# System.Reactive.Disposables as standalone library

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I'm actually learning about reactive in C#, and found that reactive offers a `Disposable` class taking an `action` (see this [link](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/f17e83b5845b65ddb7e6ce3cbf0bf9bf6a3e809c/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Disposables/Disposable.cs) for the source code). `action` is fired when `Dispose` is called. I like this idea a lot.

Does anyone know if there is a standalone library offering the dispose pattern in a object like manner?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public sealed class AnonymousDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    private int _disposed;

    public AnonymousDisposable(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _disposed, 1) == 0)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
}

public sealed class CompositeDisposable : IEnumerable<IDisposable>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IDisposable> _disposables;
    private bool _disposed;

    public CompositeDisposable()
        : this(new IDisposable[] { })
    { }

    public CompositeDisposable(IEnumerable<IDisposable> disposables)
    {
        if (disposables == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("disposables"); }
        this._disposables = new List<IDisposable>(disposables);
    }

    public CompositeDisposable(params IDisposable[] disposables)
    {
        if (disposables == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("disposables"); }
        this._disposables = new List<IDisposable>(disposables);
    }

    public void Add(IDisposable disposable)
    {
        if (disposable == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("disposable"); }
        lock (_disposables)
        {
            if (_disposed)
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                _disposables.Add(disposable);
            }
        }
    }

    public IDisposable Add(Action action)
    {
        if (action == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("action"); }
        var disposable = new AnonymousDisposable(action);
        this.Add(disposable);
        return disposable;
    }

    public IDisposable Add<TDelegate>(Action<TDelegate> add, Action<TDelegate> remove, TDelegate handler)
    {
        if (add == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("add"); }
        if (remove == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("remove"); }
        if (handler == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("handler"); }
        add(handler);
        return this.Add(() => remove(handler));
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (_disposables)
        {
            var disposables = _disposables.ToArray();
            _disposables.Clear();
            Array.ForEach(disposables, d => d.Dispose());
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_disposables)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                this.Clear();
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<IDisposable> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_disposables)
        {
            return _disposables.ToArray().AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool IsDisposed
    {
        get
        {
            return _disposed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Is it ok, if I publish the code on github?

Comment: @Moerwald - I think so. I got it from the Rx source.

Comment: While this is very useful (upvoted, thanks for that) it does NOT answer the actual question. @Moerwald please consider reopening this question so that someone can answer if there is a library to reference. I'd rather add a nuget for this than copy paste the code in my project for instance.

Comment: @julealgon - It's explicitly off-topic on SO to ask for libraries.

Comment: @Enigmativity In that case this question should be marked as such. Again, I'm not saying your post isn't useful (it is) I'm just saying that your post does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @julealgon - It provides the best answer within the rules of this site.I'm happy with that, but I've voted to close the question nevertheless.